# ASP.NET Core - Trying to create an endpoint which deletes multiple records by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to create an endpoint supposed to delete multiple ids. It should match `deleteRoom(ids: number[])`. You can see what I tried below but it doesn't match the request from the angular.

```
deleteRoom(ids: number[]) {
  return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.actionUrl}?id=${ids.toString()}`);
}
```

```cs
public class RoomsController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<RoomDto>>> GetRooms()
    {
        var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetRoomsQuery()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Ok(result);
    }

    [HttpGet("available")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<RoomDto>>> GetAvailableRooms(
        [FromQuery] DateTime from,
        [FromQuery] DateTime to,
        [FromQuery] int? departmentId,
        [FromQuery] RoomType? roomType)
    {
        var query = new GetAvailableRoomsQuery
        {
            From = from,
            To = to,
            DepartmentId = departmentId,
            RoomType = roomType
        };

        var result = await Mediator.Send(query).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Ok(result);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Create(CreateRoomCommand command)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Update(int id, UpdateRoomCommand command)
    {
        if (id != command.Id) return BadRequest();

        await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new DeleteRoomCommand {Id = id}).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{ids}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int[] ids, DeleteRoomsCommand command)
    {
        await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what is the value of `${this.actionUrl}?id=${ids.toString()}` expression?

Comment: @Chetan, ` https://localhost:5001/api/Rooms?id=9,10`

Comment: `9,10` translate to an array at server... you might want to try building your URL like `http://example.net/api/rooms?ids[0]=9&ids[1]=10` Try this first from the post man and see if you are able to call the API. Then you can change the angular code to create URL in tis form for multiple ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there two ways to use several ids in get request

1. Route values

your url should be like this ( you can use something else instead of ",")

```
http:\\....\deleteRooms\1,2,3,4
```

the action should be like this

```
[HttpGet("DeleteRooms/{ids}")] //or httpdelete
public ActionResult DeleteRooms(string ids)
{
  string[] roomIds = ids.split(",");
  ...
}
```

2. query string

```
http:\\....\deleteRooms?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4
```

the action can be

```
[HttpGet("DeleteRooms")] //or httpdelete
public ActionResult DeleteRooms(int[] ids)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second one, but you forgot `[FromQuery]`. `public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([FromQuery] int[] ids)`

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, in your API Code, you are expecting a single integer but what you are passing is a comma separated numbers (which is a string)

```
[HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
```

One option is to change `int` to `string` and do a string split within controller code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string ids)
{
  // split ids into array of int values. "1,2" into [1,2] using string.split
```

Comment: `ids = null`. This is the URL https://localhost:5001/api/Rooms?id=9,10 that the frontend is trying to send to. Also note that I could send only https://localhost:5001/api/Rooms?id=9